# Properly filter an array inside other array in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I am trying react for the first time and I am having some trouble with my filter function.
Here's the code:

So this is my render method in my component:

```
const categoryFilter = this.state.appItems.filter(item =>
      item.categories.filter(str => {
        return str.includes(active);
      })
    );

const appList = categoryFilter.map(appItem => (
      <AppItem appItem={appItem} key={appItem.id}></AppItem>
    ));

return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="flex-container">
          <NavCategories
            categories={this.state.categories}
            onClick={this.handleClick}
            active={active}
          />
          <section className="apps-list">
            <header>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Search by App" />
            </header>
            <ul>{appList}</ul>
          </section>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
```

this.state.appItems is an array coming from a json file, here's a snippet:

```
[ {
    "id": "12312",
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "test.",
    "categories": ["Voice", "Delivery", "Optimization"],
    "subscriptions": [
      {
        "name": "Trial",
        "price": 0
      },
      {
        "name": "Professional",
        "price": 3500
      }
    ]
  },]
```

Active is a string to manage active class items on another component.

Everything renders correctly, but it is never filtered even though the active state is changing everytime. 
**I have tried multiple ways, but this Filter method is getting me confused a lot because I want to filter an array thats inside another array and want to filter the whole AppItem array.**

If anyone could explain/give me some tips I would love it. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your inner filter returns an array which is always truthy. Add `.length` to the inner filter call to return an integer that will be falsey if empty and will properly trigger the outer filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.filter()` returns a new array with the filtered elements in it. So your inner filter will always return an array of at least zero elements, which evaluates to a truthy value, and your outer filter will just include every element in the original array.

Just switch your inner filter to be an `Array.includes()` instead, which will return true or false.

```
const categoryFilter = this.state.appItems.filter(item =>
  item.categories.includes(active)
);
```

Comment: I would swear that I've tried that before and it didn't work because somehow it showed me "include is not a function", but maybe I have done some changes to it. So yeah, this is correct and thanks for the explanation. :)